# "before :each do" block not being run in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In an rspec test, I have tried to initialize two variables before tests are run as follows

```
  describe "Publishing" do
    before :each do
      page_published = Page.create(attributes_for(:page))
      page_unpublished = Page.create(attributes_for(:page_unpublished))
    end
    it "returns published pages" do
      expect(Page.published).to eq [page_published]
    end
    it "returns unpublished pages" do 
      expect(Page.unpublished).to eq [page_unpublished]
    end
  end
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
1) Page Publishing returns unpublished pages
     Failure/Error: expect(Page.unpublished).to eq [page_unpublished]
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `page_unpublished' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x0000010355b8c0>
```

However, if I define the variables in each it block, there is no error.  Eg:

```
  describe "Publishing" do
    it "returns published pages" do
      page_published = Page.create(attributes_for(:page))
      expect(Page.published).to eq [page_published]
    end
    it "returns unpublished pages" do 
      page_unpublished = Page.create(attributes_for(:page_unpublished))
      expect(Page.unpublished).to eq [page_unpublished]
    end
  end
```

Why aren't the variables declared in the "before :each do" block being recognized in it blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're declaring them as variables local to the `each` block, which immediately go out of scope. You need to declare them as instance variables to make them available to other methods:

```
before :each do
  @page_published = Page.create(attributes_for(:page))
  @page_unpublished = Page.create(attributes_for(:page_unpublished))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

meagar is right. But this is also a prime place to use a [`let!`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) block instead, making it:

```
  describe "Publishing" do

    let! :page_published { Page.create(attributes_for(:page)) }
    let! :page_unpublished { Page.create(attributes_for(:page_unpublished)) }

    it "returns published pages" do
      expect(Page.published).to eq [page_published]
    end
    it "returns unpublished pages" do 
      expect(Page.unpublished).to eq [page_unpublished]
    end
  end
```